# Croogo : Different layout for different Locate

Tags: croogo

How to set different layout for different locate with "Translate Plugin"

ex:

- with link: `[http://example.com/eng]` it should render default.ctp
  for English
- and with link: `[http://example.com/ja]` it should render
  default.ctp for Japanese

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by reading the `$this->request->params['locale']` variable, which is available in the **Controller/AppController.php** file, and then change the layout according to it. It would be something like this:

```
class AppController extends CroogoAppController {

    public function beforeRender() {

    // Some code...

        // First, checks if the locale parameter is not empty
        if(!empty($this->request->params['locale']))

            // Then, sets the layout for each case.
            // In this example, we user eng and ja
            switch($this->request->params['locale']) {
                case 'eng':
                    $this->layout = 'Croogo.eng';
                    break;
                case 'esp':
                    $this->layout = 'Croogo.ja';
                break;
            }

        // If it is empty, then loads the default locale layout
        else
            $this->layout = 'Croogo.default';
    }

    // The rest of the AppController code...
}
```

Note that I used the Croogo prefix for the layout files. I did this because I wanted the layout files to be loaded from within the croogo folder. In my installation, they are located in the path **Vendor/croogo/croogo/Croogo/View/Layouts**.

Hope it helps!